# save executable from Cmake's find_program so that it can be run by Python

Tags: python, c++, cmake, swig

I'm trying to combine both C++ and Python, and for that I'm using CMake. In the CMakeLists.txt, I try to find a program:

```
# Check for Gmsh executable
find_program (GMSH gmsh [/Applications/Gmsh.app/Contents/MacOS/ /usr/bin/ /usr/local/bin/])

if(GMSH)
  message(STATUS "Found Gmsh in: ${GMSH}")
  set(HAVE_GMSH YES)
else()
  set(HAVE_GMSH NO)
endif()
message(STATUS "Setting HAVE_GMSH to: ${HAVE_GMSH}")
```

So this is able to find the executable without issues. But somehow I have to save this somewhere so that I can later call it from Python. Should this be done in a config file? What's the right way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I created a file ProjectConfig.cmake.in with the following contents:

```
# Compute paths
get_filename_component(PROJECT_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS "@CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS@")

# Our library dependencies (contains definitions for IMPORTED targets)
include("${PROJECT_CMAKE_DIR}/ProjectTargets.cmake")

# These are IMPORTED targets created by ProjectTargets.cmake
set(PROJECT_LIBRARIES core)
set(PROJECT_EXECUTABLE bar)

#cmakedefine HAVE_GMSH @HAVE_GMSH@
#cmakedefine GMSH @GMSH@
```

And the CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(TestProject)
enable_language(CXX)


# Options

# Offer the user the choice of overriding the installation directories
set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR lib CACHE PATH "Installation directory for libraries")
set(INSTALL_BIN_DIR bin CACHE PATH "Installation directory for executables")
set(INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR include CACHE PATH
  "Installation directory for header files")
if(WIN32 AND NOT CYGWIN)
  set(DEF_INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR CMake)
else()
  set(DEF_INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR lib/CMake/Project)
endif()
set(INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR ${DEF_INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR} CACHE PATH
  "Installation directory for CMake files")

# Make relative paths absolute (needed later on)
foreach(p LIB BIN INCLUDE CMAKE)
  set(var INSTALL_${p}_DIR)
  if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${${var}}")
    set(${var} "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${${var}}")
  endif()
endforeach()

# Check for Gmsh executable
find_program (GMSH gmsh [/Applications/Gmsh.app/Contents/MacOS/ /usr/bin/ /usr/local/bin/])

if(GMSH)
  message(STATUS "Found Gmsh in: ${GMSH}")
  set(HAVE_GMSH YES)
else()
  set(HAVE_GMSH NO)
endif()
message(STATUS "Setting HAVE_GMSH to: ${HAVE_GMSH}")

# Python support
#

# find Python
find_package(PythonInterp)

# find SWIG
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

message(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH: ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}")
message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES:    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core/fem)

#set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/../lib/project)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(swig/core.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(swig/core.i SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall;-c++;-shadow")
swig_add_module(core python swig/core.i core/foo.cpp)
swig_link_libraries(core project_core ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

################################################################################
# Directories
#

# set up include-directories
include_directories(
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"   # to find core/foo.hpp
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")  # to find core/config.hpp

# Add sub-directories
add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(bar)

# The interesting stuff goes here
# ===============================

# Add all targets to the build-tree export set
export(TARGETS project_core bar
  FILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ProjectTargets.cmake")

# Export the package for use from the build-tree
# (this registers the build-tree with a global CMake-registry)
export(PACKAGE Project)

# Create the ProjectConfig.cmake and ProjectConfigVersion files
file(RELATIVE_PATH REL_INCLUDE_DIR "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}"
   "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
# ... for the build tree
set(CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
configure_file(ProjectConfig.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ProjectConfig.cmake" @ONLY)
# ... for the install treew
set(CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS "\${PROJECT_CMAKE_DIR}/${REL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
configure_file(ProjectConfig.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/ProjectConfig.cmake" @ONLY)
# ... for both
configure_file(ProjectConfigVersion.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ProjectConfigVersion.cmake" @ONLY)

# Install the ProjectConfig.cmake and ProjectConfigVersion.cmake
install(FILES
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/ProjectConfig.cmake"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ProjectConfigVersion.cmake"
  DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev)

# Install the export set for use with the install-tree
install(EXPORT ProjectTargets DESTINATION
  "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev)
```

Now I'm not sure whether the location of the resulting config file (in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}) is the right place to put it. Should I instead put it in the root of the entire hierarchy? It's a big project whose structure looks like this:

```
├── AUTHORS.rst
├── CHANGELOG.rst
├── CONTRIBUTING.rst
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── core
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── ProjectConfig.cmake.in
│   ├── ProjectConfigVersion.cmake.in
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── bar
│   ├── core
│   └── swig
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── project
├── tests
│   └── unit
└── tox.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/configure_file.html) to search and replace CMake variables in it. For example, say you have a header file called `foo.h.in`:

```
#define HAVE_GMSH ${HAVE_GMSH}
```

Then in CMake you call

```
configure_file(foo.h.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/foo.h)
```

It will then replace all CMake variables in that file. The usual notation is to use `0` for "no" and `1` for "yes". So if you `set(HAVE_GMSH 1)`, it will expand to

```
#define HAVE_GMSH 1
```

You then have to make sure to include the directory the output file is in. For example `target_include_directories(mytarget ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})` (of course, it's good practice to put generated include files in a subdirectory. But prefer not to put output files in the source directory).

The CMake docs mentions you can also use special `@VARS@` to expand. In that case, use `@ONLY` with `configure_file`. It also provides `#cmakedefine`.

You can use the same approach for Python files. Many projects define author, version and so on in CMake variables, then provide a `setup.py.in` file that is searched and replaced with `configure_file`.

Comment: I updated my answer with your suggestions. It's still not clear to me how I can call the executable using Python.